# data.map is not a function in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js

I'm trying to have a simple map function create a set amount of times to show in react.

```
{times.map((time) => (
          <Pill value={time} handleTimes={handleTimes} key={time} />
        ))}
```

Currently it's receiving an error of

```
TypeError: times.map is not a function
```

The array going in looks like this from the console log,

```
...
  const [times, setTimes] = useState([]);
...
  console.log("times: ",times,"keys: ",times[0])


times:  ["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"] keys:  [
```

and the function for pills to handle times looks like this,

```
const handleTimes = (time, mode) => {
    let updatedTimes = times;
    if (mode === 'remove') {
      updatedTimes = times.filter((elem) => elem !== time);
    } else if (!updatedTimes.includes(time)) updatedTimes = [...times, time];
    setTimes(updatedTimes);
  };
```

I think that perhaps the data isn't being registered as an array when it comes in?

When looking at the type, it seems like it's a string. How can i make it an array?

```
console.log(typeof times, times)
    string ["09:00 AM","12:00 PM","03:00 PM"]
```

Comment: Are these two the only paces where you are setting times state variable?

Comment: Can you check the value for `times`. if it is `null` or `undefined` you might get this error.

Comment: Checked and put above, how do i change it from string to what it actually is?

Comment: You will have to check where you are setting is it as string. Looking at the code you have added it should be an array only.

Comment: .map does not accept type of object. Just check your code

Answer (score 0):

Nextjs hydration first and in that stage most of states are empty. so you need to check if the value null/undefined

```
 {times?.map((time) => (
           <Pill value={time} handleTimes={handleTimes} key={time} />
         ))}
```

or

```
{times && times.map((time) => (
          <Pill value={time} handleTimes={handleTimes} key={time} />
        ))}
```